# Attribute error: module ‘open3d’ has no attribute ‘data’

Tags: python, attributes, open3d

Open3d was not available on the anaconda navigator so I installed it using the anaconda prompt with the conda install command.

I wanted to try a basic code for Ball Pivoting Algorithm from http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/surface_reconstruction.html

```
import open3d as o3d
import os 
import sys 

bunny = o3d.data.BunnyMesh()
gt_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(bunny.path)
gt_mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
```

but even running the first lines I get the error

```
Attribute error: module ‘open3d’ has no attribute ‘data’
```

I’ve no idea why this is.

Comment: Is your script file named `open3d.py`?

Comment: No, I have no Python files called open3d. I am using Jupyter notebook and they are also .ipynb

Comment: Run this code and show us the output: `import open3d; print(open3d.__file__)`

Comment: It gives this output: “C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\Point_Clouds\lib\site-packages\open3d \ _ _ init_ _.py” except there are no spaces before and after the underscores around init

Comment: @JohnGordon Does that output look okay to you?

Comment: Yes that looks right.  Do you know what version of the package you have?

Comment: @JohnGordon The version is 0.11.2

Comment: The most recent package version is 0.15.1.  Can you try updating?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks a lot for your help. I’ll see if I can do that in the anaconda Prompt.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you! This worked! It let me update open3d by using pip install within conda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for open3d.data has been added in version 0.15. Upgrade the Open3d version and then try this API.

Release note: https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/releases/tag/v0.15.1